# The equation reads

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

Comment traduit-on correctement la phrase ci-après ?

> After the simplification, the corresponding mth-order deformation equation **reads**

Je pense à une phrase comme suit :

> Après la simplification, l'équation de déformation de l'ordre m correspondant (reads)...

Quel verbe rend *read* dans ce contexte ? Peut-on employer **lire** (lit ici) ? Est-ce mieux d'employer **se lire** ?

Comment: Side remark: If “corresponding” applies to the order, you should write “de l'ordre m correspondant” (masculine agreement). In the case it applies to the “équation de deformation” it should be “d'ordre m”, without an article (well, unless it is the m-th order of something else).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez  Thanks a lot. You are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***The equation reads*** est une expression spécifique à l'anglais.

Une équation étant incapable de lire quoi que ce soit, *read* signifie ici *can be read as*, *indicate*.

Puisqu'il s'agit d'un changement après une modification, le plus logique serait de dire

> Après la simplification, l'équation de déformation de l'ordre m correspondant **devient** (*now reads*)

Utiliser *se lit* est aussi grammaticalement possible mais plus discutable :

> Après la simplification, l'équation de déformation de l'ordre m correspondant **se lit**

*Se lire* est plus utilisé pour expliquer comment comprendre ou lire à haute voix quelque chose plutôt que pour simplement indiquer un libellé.

On ne traduira pas par exemple:

> The speedometer reads 100 mph.

par

> Le compteur de vitesse <s>se lit</s> 160 km/h.

mais par

> Le compteur de vitesse indique (ou affiche) 160 km/h.

Comment: Très bien. Merci beaucoup :-)!

Comment: On peut aussi dire **s'écrit**

Answer (score 0):

Oui absolument pour **se lit** pour *the equation reads*. **usuel!!**

On traduit aussi communément et dans le même sens : **is as follows**